# Avoid Alarm Repeat In android

Tags: android, android-alarms

hi there i am new to android development i m developing an application which is related to alarm with `notification` while i set alarm at particular time all work perfectly and alarm notified correctly but the alarm `notification` repeat at some times while i m not repeating it how can i avoid this problem.

this is my code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("ti", name);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);      
final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();        
switch(Cun.valueOf(repeat)) {
case No:        
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
 break;
}
```

Comment: @Aʌɐpɥɐuı Please do not use code formatting to simply highlight key words. It should only be used for actual inline code.

Answer (score 0):

After the alarm notifies for the first time, cancel it by using :

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
intent.putExtra("ti", name);
intent.putExtra("id", id);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE); 
alarmManager.cancel ( pendingIntent );
```

Comment: Where did you place the block of code that I suggested ? It should be placed inside the **AlarmReceiver** class.

Comment: no i place this code in my main activity..from that activity alarm ill be generate from sql lite

Comment: If you want to cancel the alarm after its first notification, you should put my block of code in **AlarmReceiever**, since if the **AlarmReceiever** is called, you are sure the alarm notified once, and then you cancel it there, along with your code/logic.